# Using Angular ui-routing resolve to load requirejs modules

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, requirejs

I'm trying to use require.js to lazy load some of my dependencies in angular, and I'm having a few issues.

I believe the following code should try to load the register controller before angular neeeds it (via angular-ui-router):

```
  .state('register', {
    url: '/register',
    class: 'login',
    title: 'Register',
    templateUrl: 'app/security/register.view.html',
    controller: 'RegisterController',
    controllerAs: 'register',
    resolve: {
      require: function ($q) {
        return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
          console.log('security/register.controller loading')
          require(['security/register.controller'], function () {
            console.log('security/register.controller loaded')
            resolve()
          })
        })
      }
    }
  })
```

But when I switch from the login state to the register state, I get the following output in the console:

```
RouteChanged Login
security/register.controller loading
security/register.controller loaded
RouteChanged Register
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=RegisterController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
```

So even though the resolve runs, angular throws an error saying it can't find the RegisterController.

---

[Here's a link to a plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/WJnWd7107tURhc1uyIKb?p=preview) As you can see, the controllers aren't loaded when you click on the links, and an error message is shown in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally user ui router with the $ocLazyLoad provider https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad

Its more simple and works great. Here is a example:

```
     .state('dashboards.dashboard_2', {
                url: "/dashboard_2",
                templateUrl: "views/dashboard_2.html",
                data: { pageTitle: 'Dashboard 2' },
                resolve: {
                    loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                            {
                                serie: true,
                                name: 'angular-flot',
                                files: [ 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.time.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js', 'js/plugins/flot/curvedLines.js', 'js/plugins/flot/angular-flot.js', ]
                            },
                            {
                                files: ['js/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.2.min.js', 'js/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.2.css']
                            },
                            {
                                files: ['js/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js']
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'ui.checkbox',
                                files: ['js/bootstrap/angular-bootstrap-checkbox.js']
                            }
                        ]);
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: I found that after I posted my answer, it looks pretty useful. I'll check it out, thanks :)

Comment: After having investigated ocLazyLoad, it seems like it doesn't handle dependencies, so I have to go back to specifying all of the file names manually. Is that true?

Comment: How so? Because in that example, all that scripts are depencencies for the module to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
resolve: {
      require: function ($q) {
        //tell ui-router to wait
        var deferred = $q.defer(); 
          console.log('security/register.controller loading')

          require(['security/register.controller'], function () {
            console.log('security/register.controller loaded')
            deferred.resolve()
          });
         return deferred.promise; 
      }
```

Comment: I tried that and got the same result. The interesting thing is that if I add the require statement earlier in my code it also fails to load, so I think it's something to do with how I'm organising and loading my modules.

Comment: what does your controller looks like? do you have require as one of inject params

Comment: I've tried it both with the inject param and without. It's calling it in the correct order even without the param, but still not loading properly.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was with my flawed assumption that you could add a controller to angular after bootstrap, which apparently you can, just not the same way as you do pre-bootstrap. If you're adding them after bootstrap you need to cache a copy of the controller provider, and then register the controller with that provider. I added the following code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])

var cachedProviders = {}
  app.config(['$controllerProvider',
    function(controllerProvider) {
      cachedProviders.$controllerProvider = controllerProvider;
    }
  ]);
  $(function (){
    app.controller = function (name, controller) {
      console.log('Loading (using post-boostrap loader):', name)
      cachedProviders.$controllerProvider.register.apply(this, arguments)
    }
  })
```

To my app module file and it started working. I'm not quite sure if this will have negative side effects yet, but for now it does what I want.